# Call React-native from custom component

Tags: java, android, events, react-native

I am fairly new to react-native and I cannot figure out how I can call an event from a custom component.
The component I am using is react-native-android-snackbar and I am trying to check if the snackbar is active.

By inspecting the [code](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-android-snackbar/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/lugg/ReactSnackbar/ReactSnackbarModule.java) I have found that there is an event called EVENT_SHOWN. This is exactly what I need but unfortunally I don't know how I can check for this event.

I tried the following:

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {username: '', password: '',spinnerVisible:false};
        this._event = this._event.bind(this);
        DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('EVENT_SHOW',this._event);
    }
    _event(event: Event){
        Alert.alert("Event handler","Event handler");
    }
```

But unfortunally it doesn't work the function doesn't get called when I activate the snackbar.

Hope somebody can help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EVENT_SHOWN` is native side of event, the [JS](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-android-snackbar/blob/master/index.android.js) event is just `shown`.
So try

```
Snackbar.addEventListener('shown', this._event);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice to look into that file to look for the correct event names. although I tried changing it but it still doesn't call my event handler function when it shows or closes. Is there something I might be missing.

Comment: Hero! That worked wonderfull. Could you maybe explain why this works ? :)

Comment: That js file is JavaScript bridge to native module. It exposes functions like `show`, `dismiss`, `addEventListener`, `removeEventListener` so that they can be used in your React Native app.

Comment: Last question :) Is there also a way to see from which event my function is triggered ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. Use different callbacks for each event.